# Iterating over mysql data and posting to excel with phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I would like to produce something like [this](http://nqcl.alphybay.com/word.png) in an excel file but it produces [this](http://nqcl.alphybay.com/phpexcel.png) which is not what i want. I would like the output to be exactly the same. If the number of tests are four, then four tests are dynamically printed vertically in a cell in excel file as in the word document plus the additional details

here is more details of the number of tests and their details.

```
    $trd = $this->getRequestedTestsDisplay2($labref);  //An array of objects 4 in total
    $coa_details = $this->getAssayDissSummary($labref); //details as shown http://nqcl.alphybay.com/word.png
```

phpword code

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($trd); $i++) {

            foreach ($coa_details as $coa) {

                if ($coa->test_id == $trd[$i]->test_id) {
                    $determined = $coa->determined;
                    $remarks = $coa->verdict;
                }
            }
            $table3->addRow(400);
            $table3->addCell(1500)->addText($trd[$i]->name);
            $table3->addCell(1500)->addText($trd[$i]->methods);
            $table3->addCell(1700)->addText($trd[$i]->compedia);
            $table3->addCell(1800)->addText($trd[$i]->specification);
            $table3->addCell(1700)->addText('DETERMINED', $style3);
            $table3->addCell(1500)->addText($trd[$i]->complies);
        }
```

phpxcel code

```
 $row = 19;
    $col=1;
    $worksheet= $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($trd); $i++) {

        foreach ($coa_details as $coa) {
                  if ($coa->test_id == $trd[$i]->test_id) {
                $determined = $coa->determined;
                $remarks = $coa->verdict;
            }            
               $worksheet
                ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $trd[$i]->name)
                ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $trd[$i]->methods)
                ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $trd[$i]->compedia)
                ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $trd[$i]->specification)
                ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $trd[$i]->complies);
                 $col++;
        }
        $row++;      

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps resetting column for each row, and not overwriting each value in the same row/column:

```
$row = 19;
$worksheet= $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($trd); $i++) {
    $col=1;
    foreach ($coa_details as $coa) {
        if ($coa->test_id == $trd[$i]->test_id) {
            $determined = $coa->determined;
            $remarks = $coa->verdict;
        }            
        $worksheet
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $trd[$i]->name)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $trd[$i]->methods)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $trd[$i]->compedia)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $trd[$i]->specification)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $trd[$i]->complies);
    }
    $row++;      
}
```

**EDIT**

You mean something like:

```
$row = 19;
$worksheet= $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($trd); $i++) {
    $col=1;
    foreach ($coa_details as $coa) {
        if ($coa->test_id == $trd[$i]->test_id) {
            $determined = $coa->determined;
            $remarks = $coa->verdict;
        }
    }
    $worksheet
        ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $trd[$i]->name)
        ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $trd[$i]->methods)
        ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $trd[$i]->compedia)
        ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $trd[$i]->specification)
        ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row, $trd[$i]->complies);
    }
    $row++;      
}
```

Comment: Hello mark, that works but it makes three more of the same thing horizontally and I just need one, see [here](http://nqcl.alphybay.com/duplicate.png), more suggestions!

Comment: So what's the relationship between $coa_details and $trd? I'm having a hard time understanding that, because I'm guessing there must be 3 $coa_details records for each $trd[$i]

Comment: I was looking up and comparing tests returned by $trd and $coa_body, wherever the test id's match, there is a specific value to be printed in a given cell under  the same $labref, ok, what if we took $trd which also acts as a counter for the moment, how would it look?